# Dimension dependence

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory

The question is related [to this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398928/dimensions-analysis-in-differential-equation)

The time averaged total energy, $\bar E$,
has the following $\varepsilon$ expansion in $D$ dimension:
\begin{equation}
\bar{E}=\varepsilon^{2-D}\frac{E_0}{2\lambda}+ \varepsilon^{4-D}E_1\,,
\quad {\rm where}\quad E_0=\int d^{D}\zeta\,S^2\,,
\tag{1}\end{equation}
As one sees from Eq (1)the leading order behavior
of the time averaged total energy is ${\bar E}\propto\varepsilon^{2-D}$.
This implies that the $\varepsilon$-dependence of $\bar E$ changes essentially
at $D=2$.
In dimensions $D>2$ the total energy {\sl increases} without any bound
for decreasing values of $\varepsilon$.

> My question is that why the equation (1) is essentially depended on 2
>   dimensions? why not 4?
>   [Please see the article equation (39)](http://arxiv.org/abs/0802.3525)
>   And can you please elaborate the equation (1) a please?

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: I have stated that" My question is that why the equation (1) is essentially depended on 2 dimensions? why not 4? Please see the article equation (39) And can you please elaborate the equation (1) a please?"

Comment: Again, my same question. What do you mean by the Equation is dependent on 2 dimensions? Do you mean that it only holds in 2 dimensions? Then you could as well write $2$""
instead of $D$.

Comment: Please don't re-add the dimensional-analysis tag, it's only for situations where you use the system of units to your advantage. It has nothing to do with spatial dimensions.

Comment: but I think, it's about spatial dimensions and the equations explains that what dimension could be valid for the Energy equation.

Comment: @Raisa: Please see this: http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/dimensional-analysis/info/.